# VS2022 - vb.NET 4.8 Project - Calling SetWindowsHookEx() returns "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow"

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-hook, setwindowshookex

Our software has worked fine before in VS2010 but we've had to upgrade and figured we'd lash out and upgrade to VS2022 and leverage what is new to .NET 4.8 framework.

We had an existing keyboard hook library that allows our software to control our machines via keyboard, a global hook so far has been the best answer in VS2010 running .NET 4.0.

Just not sure why this is suddenly an issue in VS2022.

The code for doing this is quite Common and general, i'll include it here:

```
Public Class KeyboardHook
  <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
  Private Overloads Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal HookProc As KBDLLHookProc, ByVal hInstance As IntPtr, ByVal wParam As Integer) As Integer
  End Function
  <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
  Private Overloads Shared Function CallNextHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
  End Function
  <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
  Private Overloads Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer) As Boolean
  End Function

  <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
  Private Structure KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
   Public vkCode As UInt32
   Public scanCode As UInt32
   Public flags As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags
   Public time As UInt32
   Public dwExtraInfo As UIntPtr
  End Structure

  <Flags()>
  Private Enum KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags As UInt32
   LLKHF_EXTENDED = &H1
   LLKHF_INJECTED = &H10
   LLKHF_ALTDOWN = &H20
   LLKHF_UP = &H80
  End Enum

  Public Shared Event KeyDown(ByVal Key As Keys)
  Public Shared Event KeyUp(ByVal Key As Keys)

  Private Const WH_KEYBOARD_LL As Integer = 13
  Private Const HC_ACTION As Integer = 0
  Private Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
  Private Const WM_KEYUP = &H101
  Private Const WM_SYSKEYDOWN = &H104
  Private Const WM_SYSKEYUP = &H105
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD0 = &H60
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD1 = &H61
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD2 = &H62
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD3 = &H63
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD4 = &H64
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD5 = &H65
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD6 = &H66
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD7 = &H67
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD8 = &H68
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD9 = &H69



  Private Delegate Function KBDLLHookProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer

  Private KBDLLHookProcDelegate As KBDLLHookProc = New KBDLLHookProc(AddressOf KeyboardProc)
  Private HHookID As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero


  Private Function KeyboardProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
   If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
    Dim struct As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    Select Case wParam
     Case WM_KEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYDOWN
      RaiseEvent KeyDown(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
     Case WM_KEYUP, WM_SYSKEYUP
      RaiseEvent KeyUp(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
    End Select
   End If
   Return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam)
  End Function

  Public Sub SetHook()
   Try
    HHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KBDLLHookProcDelegate, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)).ToInt32, 0)
    'HHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KBDLLHookProcDelegate, Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)).ToInt32, 0)
    If HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
     Throw New Exception("Could not set keyboard hook")
    End If
   Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("keyboard hook Error: " & ex.Message)
   End Try

  End Sub

  Public Sub UnHook()
   If Not HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(HHookID)
   End If
  End Sub

 End Class
```

The error appears to be in the SetHook method where the HHookID is being set by the SetWindowsHookEx()

It returns a "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" error.

The actual value returned is a massive negative number.

I have tried enabling "Ignore integer overflow checks" in project settings but this still returns the exception and also, of course, does not hook the keyboard.

To save some time, I'd love to keep working on VS2022 as it is moving forward so a solution would be good. :)

I Also tried following the path of Disabling VSHost but I see there is no option for it in VS2022 under the Debugging section of the project.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There are bugs, they'll byte when the code runs in 64-bit mode.  HHOOK is IntPtr, not Integer.  The variable is good, but the SetWindowsHookEx return type declaration is not.  Same story for the KBDLLHookProc delegate declaration, return value is IntPtr.  Finally the hInstance parameter of SetWindowsHookEx, correctly declared as IntPtr but using ToInt32() to make the call is not correct and the likely cause of the OverflowException.

Comment: You should turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties. There's some code there that will not compile when you do and such code can be problematic. You should also turn it `On` in the VS options, so it is `On` by default for all future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hans we have a solution. Good spot Hans!

To confirm, the old code worked on VS2010, .NET 4.0

Platform is set to AnyCPU to keep it universal.

Updated code:

```
 Public Class KeyboardHook


  <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
  Private Overloads Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal HookProc As KBDLLHookProc, ByVal hInstance As IntPtr, ByVal wParam As Integer) As IntPtr
  End Function
  <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
  Private Overloads Shared Function CallNextHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
  End Function
  <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
  Private Overloads Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer) As Boolean
  End Function

  <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
  Private Structure KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
   Public vkCode As UInt32
   Public scanCode As UInt32
   Public flags As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags
   Public time As UInt32
   Public dwExtraInfo As UIntPtr
  End Structure

  <Flags()>
  Private Enum KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags As UInt32
   LLKHF_EXTENDED = &H1
   LLKHF_INJECTED = &H10
   LLKHF_ALTDOWN = &H20
   LLKHF_UP = &H80
  End Enum

  Public Shared Event KeyDown(ByVal Key As Keys)
  Public Shared Event KeyUp(ByVal Key As Keys)

  Private Const WH_KEYBOARD_LL As Integer = 13
  Private Const HC_ACTION As Integer = 0
  Private Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
  Private Const WM_KEYUP = &H101
  Private Const WM_SYSKEYDOWN = &H104
  Private Const WM_SYSKEYUP = &H105
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD0 = &H60
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD1 = &H61
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD2 = &H62
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD3 = &H63
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD4 = &H64
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD5 = &H65
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD6 = &H66
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD7 = &H67
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD8 = &H68
  Private Const VK_NUMPAD9 = &H69



  Private Delegate Function KBDLLHookProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer

  Private KBDLLHookProcDelegate As KBDLLHookProc = New KBDLLHookProc(AddressOf KeyboardProc)
  Private HHookID As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero


  Private Function KeyboardProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
   If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
    Dim struct As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    Select Case wParam
     Case WM_KEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYDOWN
      RaiseEvent KeyDown(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
     Case WM_KEYUP, WM_SYSKEYUP
      RaiseEvent KeyUp(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
    End Select
   End If
   Return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam)
  End Function

  Public Sub SetHook()
   Try
    HHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KBDLLHookProcDelegate, Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)), 0)
    If HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
     Throw New Exception("Could not set keyboard hook")
    End If
   Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("keyboard hook Error: " & ex.Message)
   End Try

  End Sub

  Public Sub UnHook()
   If Not HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(HHookID)
   End If
  End Sub

 End Class
```